# Excel: Add number to rows that are all with numbers

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add a percentage (%) to all rows from certain columns in a large Excels?

Example:

```
Product 1           |         Option 1       |         Option 2
                    | without VAT | with VAT | without VAT | with VAT
product attribute 1 |    135.00   |  167.40  |   196.00    |  243.04
product attribute 2 |    204.0    |  252.96  |   264.00    |  327.36
```

What I want to do is add +5% to all prices at "without VAT" without manually going through each cell.

"with VAT" already has a formula that takes "without VAT" in consideration, so I need only "without VAT" to have an additional +5%.

Products are split by an empty row between them.

Comment: Well, if you're wondering about the math, it's 196+(196*.05) [As an example]. If you're wondering about the formula, it's =A3+(A3*.05) [A3 being the cell you're adding 5% to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, assuming Without Vat is column A, the formula would be:

```
=A1+(A1*.05)
```

I hope this is what you're looking for!

Let me know if there is something else or I misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks! This kinda works (though edited because I get circular error): I don't go through each cell automatically, but it doesn't work on empty cells. I'll just select which cell to apply the formula.

Comment: If you don't want it to work on empty cells, change it to =IF(A1<>"",A1+(A1*.05),"")    This basically says, if A1 isn't blank, apply the formula, otherwise, leave it blank.